# Modifying a transaction that has started at a different scope is not allowed

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am currently using DBT to load data into Snowflake.
I am creating an incremental model which runs the execute immediate $$ to run the logic for the process. Execute immediate statement includes (create/insert/update temporary table and does merge on a production table). This works fine on SF web interface. But, its giving below error on dbt.

"Modifying a transaction that has started at a different scope is not allowed."

Any feedbacks would be appreciated.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Maybe you can get more info from https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#stored-procedures-and-transactions